# Storing macros in a Word document/template with backwards (and forwards) compatibility?

Tags: windows, macos, microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-word-2003

**The issue:** I've inherited a .doc file created with Word 2003 (Windows, obviously). I'm a Mac user and have Word 2011. The .doc file I've inherited contains a number of macros for typesetting some simple mathematics and would be used as a template for students submitting problem sets in online courses. (I'm not crazy about the use of Word, but it's what I'm stuck with.) The problem is that the .doc opens fine and the macros work, but if I save it as a .doc the macros are stripped. The macros are preserved in a .docm, but then the file is unreadable by the creator who uses Word 2003 and is pretty wed to it (he's an old-school Word power user who has customized his setup extensively whereas I avoid Word like the plague).

While he uses Word 2003 on Windows and I use Word 2011 on Mac, the file would also be utilized by students who may use a wide variety of Word versions on different platforms. (Though most will probably have newer releases, so if the only answer is that my colleague has to abandon his much beloved Word 2003 and switch to a release after Word 20XX, I *might* be able to convince him to switch.)

**The Question:** How can he create files with macros embedded on Word 2003 that I can use and save in a format that both preserves macros and is readable/writable across a wide variety of Word releases (again with saves preserving macros)?

(Bonus points if the format could also be used (with macros) successfully by an open source Word replacement like Open Office or Libre Office -- since I'd prefer not to force students to purchase software if they aren't already Word users.)

Comment: Open Office and Libre Office macros are not compatible with Word.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, that's one dream dashed. Thanks for the info.